# .get() func for button widget in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to get information from the button to pass an if conditional inside of a window. I am planning to add +10 widgets that have functions bound to them after that condition.  I would appreciate it if you could answer.

```
from tkinter import *

condition = None

window = Tk()

button = Button(window,text="button",command= lambda: condition == True)
button.pack()

if condition:
    label = Label(window,text="hello this is a label")
    label.pack()

window.mainloop()
```

I tried this but it couldn't pass the if conditional.

Comment: `lambda: condition == True` doesn't do anything useful. Also please look at how [event driven programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event-driven_programming) works - you respond to events using callback functions.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to get an information from button to pass an if conditional
> inside of an window

Create function.

Snippet modified:

```
def _condition():
    if not condition:
        label = Label(window,text="hello this is a label")
        label.pack()


button = Button(window,text="button",command=_condition)
button.pack()
```

Comment: i am planning to add +10 widget after that condition, but is it reasonable to use the same method to pass the condition?

Comment: Please add this to your question

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of understanding, Let me assume that you want to run two functions simultaneously on clicking the button. (You can expand this for 10 widgets). One is to hide a label with text 'welcome' and another is to show the label "hello this is a label". And you want these two as different widgets

Let me assume that the above two function should run while clicking the button provided if a check_button is on(condition)

create a `function` say `run_functions` before declaring `window = Tk()`. Create functions for each widgets before the function `run_function`.

The above two operation can be done in a same `Label`. But since you wanted different widgets should perform different actions on clicking the button, I'm declaring as different widgeds. (For the sake of understanding)
Create a `Label` with empty-text and pack it. If you want the text should appear after the button, declare the `Label` after button. If you want the text to appear before the button, declare it before declaring the button. Similarly create a Label with the text 'Welcome' and pack it.

The idea is like this: when you mention a function name in any widget with `command=function_name`, it means: By default the mentioned function will not run. If the user does any action in the widget, the function will run. For instance, when you mention `Button(command=run_functions)`, By default, the run_function will not run. If the user clicks the button(here the user's action is 'clicking the Button'), then the function run_functions will run.)

So we can add the conditional statement inside `run_functions` like: if the checkbutton is on, run other two functions.

```
from tkinter import *

#create a function 'show_label'     
def show_label(): label.configure(text="hello this is a label")

#create a function 'hide_label'
def hide_label():lbl.configure(text='')

#create a function run_functions
def run_functions():
    #condition  
    if yesvar.get() == 1:
        show_label()
        hide_label()


#add geometry to the window
window = Tk()
window.geometry(('200x100'))
        
#example widget -added for example for a condition
yesvar = IntVar()
yes = Checkbutton(window, variable = yesvar, text='yes, Run the functions')
yes.pack(side='top')

#create a Label with empty text and pack it
label = Label(window, text='')
label.pack(side='top')

#create a Label with text 'Welcome~!' and pack it
lbl = Label(window, text='Welcome')
lbl.pack(side='top')

#Using command=srun_functions in the widget Button, call the function 'run_functions' 
button = Button(window,text="button",command=run_functions)
button.pack(side='top')

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: OP wants 10 widgets.

Comment: Let the OP expand it to 10 widgets

Comment: It should be `yesvar = IntVar()` instead of `yesVar = IntVar()`. And it should be `if yesvar.get() == 1` instead of `if yesvar == 1` (first 2 mistakes I found). Please run the code that you post as an answer to make sure there aren't any simple mistakes like that.

Comment: @TheLizzard. Thank you. corrected. I'm sorry it's happened due to oversight

Comment: thank you for your explanation. I changed `show_label()` function to  `def show_label(): label.pack()` and deleted the pack() function inside of the window , because I feel like that might work with Label but when I tried to use other widgets like entry or button it still shows the frames. I also did the same thing with hide, but instead of .pack() i used .destroy() ( i hope that doesn't make it slower in longer terms ).